# Is it ok to have only a submit button in an html form?

Tags: html, forms

Pretty simple question is it ok to have a form in html like this,

```
<form class="spacer" action="" method="post">
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I searched on google but could not find anything?

Comment: What do you want this form to do?

Comment: Yes I am back to the same page, @steve adams just need to make a post request so php recognises it

Comment: @Prasanth: `If action is the empty string, let action be the document's address.`

Comment: @cgweb87 So you'd like (for example) a php script to see that $_POST has been used? In that case, yes, this would do the trick.

Comment: @animuson although it is best to put the current address in, as it actually makes an extra header request on the page if you do not, as explained in Yslow :)

Comment: The html is valid. It is possible to make a  form like this.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is.

There is no requirement that a `<form>` contains any elements, `<input>` or otherwise. (However, most *useful* forms generally contain a "submit" input and other relevant elements...)

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks don't know why this isn't documented

Comment: @cgweb87 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element (It is only documented in the positive case, as far as I can see.)